# Use of paste0 in conditonalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use a conditionalPanel in a renderUI where the condition includes a paste0. In the toy example below, Test 1 works just fine but Test 2 always displays the text, that is the condition is always set to TRUE. The reason I need to use a paste0 is that eventually I want many such tagLists, that is have a statement like `condition = 'paste0(input.test, i)=="b"'`.
I suspect the problem is that condition is supposed to be a JavaScipt and I need some variation of index.test.indexOf(paste0('2')), but I have not been able to get it to work.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   uiOutput("inp1"),
   uiOutput("inp2")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$inp1=renderUI({
     tagList(radioButtons("test1", "Test 1", choices=c("a","b"),inline=TRUE),
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.test1=="b"', HTML("Works")))
   })
   output$inp2=renderUI({
     tagList(radioButtons("test2", "Test 2", choices=c("a","b"),inline=TRUE),
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'paste0(input.test, 2)=="b"',HTML("Doesn't Work")))
   })
}
```

Comment: Does `condition = paste0(input.test, '2', '=="b"')` work?

Comment: No, it yields an error: object 'input.test' not found. I have gotten that error a number of times when trying different variations

Comment: "eventually I want many such tagLists": in which case, *seriously* consider using [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). Your code will be more compact, easier to maintain and more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass entire condition as string -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("inp1"),
  uiOutput("inp2")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$inp1=renderUI({
    tagList(radioButtons("test1", "Test 1", choices=c("a","b"),inline=TRUE),
            conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.test1=="b"', HTML("Works")))
  })
  output$inp2=renderUI({
    tagList(radioButtons("test2", "Test 2", choices=c("a","b"),inline=TRUE),
            conditionalPanel(condition = paste0('input.test', 2, '=="b"'),HTML("This works too")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```